# Was it good seeing him?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, idiomatic-language

A man hasn't seen his son for a long time. He finally does. Later that same day he talks with his ex-wife on the phone. She asks him:

> Was it good seeing him?

Is it OK and natural to use 'good' in the above sentence?

Comment: Why do you think there might be a problem? What context would you use this sentence? Who are you talking to (or writing to?) Who is "him"?  What sort of answer are you looking for? What information do you want the other person to give you?   There is lots and lots that you could include in this question!

Comment: It doesn't sound particularly idiomatic, but to know what is better I would have to know the context and what you are asking.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain the meaning that is wanted and the context. It *might* be an okay choice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sentence is correct. [CoGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Comprehensive_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) (section 18.34) calls this "extraposition of *-ing* clauses".

The "original" sentence would be:

> Seeing him was good.

The structure is clear. However, we can extrapose the -ing clause ("seeing him") by introducing the pronoun "it":

> It was good seeing him.

Your sentence is simply the yes/no interrogative version of that:

> Was it good seeing him?

Whether this sentence is actually "OK and natural" depends on context (the surrounding text, the intended tone and register, etc.).